# Force netstat to always return results in English language, irrespective of system language?

Tags: powershell, language, netstat

Is there a way to call netstat commands (e.g. `netstat -an`) but return the results in English irrespective of the system language?

Background: the reason I wish to find a way is because some software that parses netstat output only works for English OS languages, so I hope make netstat always return English results so parsing doesn't fail.

Note:

I would be interested in an answer that is operating system independent, but if a single operating system must be chosen, then Windows is the operating system I actually need this for at the moment, as the commands are being run from powershell.

#### Use case

I am [calling netstat](https://github.com/stevecondylios/netstat/blob/master/R/netstat.R#L20-L25), then parsing the results. Because I wrote the parser to work for the English results, it sometimes [doesn't work](https://community.rstudio.com/t/free-port-with-netstat/93886) for people on systems whose language isn't English.

Comment: How about temp. changing the system language via command line?

Comment: @Albin is it possible to do that in a way that I can be sure it will revert back to whatever it was previously immediately afterwards? (I'm sending this code to many other people in different languages, so I don't want to mess up someone's computer)

Comment: You could save the language before changing it, but honestly I wouldn't trust other people to do it correctly if it is automated - there is always s.th. unexpected when dealing with layer 8 (users). I would rather write a HowTo.

Comment: @Albin that sounds sensible. In case it's useful, [here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/netstat/blob/master/R/netstat.R#L20-L25)'s the code I'm trying to ensure runs in English. It's just one line calling netstat. Basically the library simply makes it so the user doesn't have to specify a free port on their machine, so it gets netstat output and deduces which ports are free.

Comment: I would advice you to add the code and additional explanations from the comments to your question, sort of an appendix at the end.

Comment: @Albin done, please let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: this `Get-NetTCPConnection` will give you most of what you seem to want. this `[enum]::GetNames('Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetTCPConnection.State')` will give you the possible values of the `.State` property. if that is not in your preferred language, you can make a hashtable to do a lookup using the `.State._Value` byte values as your keys.

Comment: Follow @Lee_Dailey; you could check `[enum]::GetNames([System.Net.NetworkInformation.TcpState])` as well (their _enum_ isn't available for me (pshell 5.1)).